# any environment like CARLA compatible with automated driving toolbox

Tags: matlab, carla

I am using MATLAB automated driving toolbox, I need to have an environment like CARLA which can be implemented in MATLAB in windows and be compatible with Object Detection (YOLO), I would appreciate if there is any help to address this issue.

I tried CARLA MATLAB interface and it was not working

Answer (score 0):

According to

https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/470709-how-can-you-connect-the-carla-autonomous-driving-simulator-with-simulink

you need the [MATLAB ROS Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ros/index.html?s_tid=srchtitle_ros%2520toolbox_1)

ROS: Robot Operating System

MATLAB ROS System Requirements [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ros/gs/ros-system-requirements.html?s_tid=srchtitle_ros%2520toolbox_3).

[What is MATLAB ROS Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/what-is-ros-toolbox-1566804330478.html?s_tid=srchtitle_ros%2520toolbox_4)  video 2'.

This is the main one:
[Get started with MATLAB & Simulink ROS Toolbox](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/ros/getting-started-with-ros-toolbox.html?s_tid=srchtitle_ros%2520toolbox_6)

[MATLAB Apps with ROS](https://uk.mathworks.com/videos/matlab-and-simulink-robotics-arena-matlab-apps-with-ros-1526379787323.html?s_tid=srchtitle_ros%2520toolbox_15)  video 20'.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, unfortunately since I do not have the ROS toolbox in MATLAB and I have to buy it, I cannot use it.

Comment: All MATLAB toolboxes cost £30.- only,  for students, as well as for home use. MATLAB Home toolboxes are also priced at £30.- each.

Comment: What ROS are you using?